# Exclude files from the JetBrains ReSharper commandLine tool InspectCode.exe

Tags: xml, configuration, resharper

I'm hoping to demonstrate the value of ReSharper to my team. I want to try the commandline tool [InspectCode](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode) JetBrains has released.

It runs fine when I point it at my solution, but analyses all the test projects, and some generated files. I want to exclude them from inspection. The documentation says

> If you want to configure InspectCode on a CI server, you can make all configurations locally with ReSharper.

For various reasons I can't install even the demo version of ReSharper at the moment to do this. The InspectCode.exe tool can generate a configuration file, but it is not clear how I can manually edit this to exclude certain files or projects from analysis. Here is the auto generated XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InspectCodeOptions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NoSolutionWideAnalysis>false</NoSolutionWideAnalysis>
  <IncludedProjects />
  <SuppressBuildInSettings>false</SuppressBuildInSettings>
  <Debug>false</Debug>
  <Extensions />
  <Properties />
  <DumpIssuesTypes>false</DumpIssuesTypes>
</InspectCodeOptions>
```

How can I modify this XML file to exclude files ending in "generated.cs", or any file or project with "test" in the name?

### UPDATE

derigel: I see what I did wrong. I have reset my ReSharper configuration and started again. Now all I changed in the settings was to go to ReSharper → Options → Code Inspection → Settings → Edit Items to Skip.

I added a file mask, "*test*".

Clicking save-to -> [SOLUTIONNAME] team shared saved it to the file as I expected. However the configuration file now looks like this:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/ExcludedFiles/FileMasksToSkip/=_002Atest_002A/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
```

Which InspectCode.exe does not like. It gives me this error if I use `/config=FILENAME.DotSettings`:

> Failed to load options from file 
>   D:\SVN\Development\branches\OpenSolutionClinicalID_v1.0_Development\src\OpenSolutionConnect.sln.DotSettings. 
>   Caused b y: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML
>   document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: 
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'> was not
>   expected. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderInspectCodeSettingsData.Read3_InspectCodeOptions() 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) 
>   at
>   JetBrains.CommandLine.Common.Options.OptionsUtils.DeserializeFromFile[T](FileSystemPath
>   pathToConfig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation describe the settings for your solution, not the tool itself.

For example, here are settings for generated files: *[Configuring Code Inspection Settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#d2375e280)* and here about excluding files: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#d2375e201

After you change them and save to the solution-shared level, there will be file `<solutionname>.sln.dotsettings` which will be taken into account by command line tools.

Although this is an XML file, it's not very editable by hands. Why can't you install trial instance of ReSharper and configure all you need?

Comment: I have already used up my 30 day trial of ReSharper previously, before these tools were available.

Comment: Pete, you can raise a request at our support system http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/ We'll extend your trial period.

Comment: Thanks derigel! Oddly I reinstalled the trial in preparation and have a fresh 30 day trial available. Anyway, I followed the instructions from http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode but this did not update my SolutonName.sln.DotSettings file as stated, it updated C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings. I tried pointing the tool to this file instead and it errors saying it is invalid... feel like I'm missing a critical step here

Comment: Yep, you missed to save your customized settings to shared layer (which, usually, committed to VCS and available to all devs and tools), not your personal one.
Take a look here http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/09/21/save-or-save-to-in-resharper-options/

Comment: thanks again for your help, still stuggling with this, see my post (should I have added it as an edit to my original question?)